# Google Sheets OnEdit Split

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to get the difference in hr/mins between the timestamp of the google form and 8:00 am. Currently, I am using the split function to break the timestamp up and then I am using the diff in time to calculate mins.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WU_dDxRTX2JWqL1b3e8SHh0GMOfjZ9YT1LV7dADVmz8/edit?usp=sharing

Would anyone be able to make this occur onedit?

Thank you!

Comment: Which column do you edit to make onEdit() trigger? There is another trigger which I believe is suitable for your issue. The onFormSubmit Trigger runs the function when a response was submitted in form. You can use it to create columns during the first run and calculate the values of date, time and time late. May I know which one do you prefer?

Answer (score 0):

try in row 1:

```
={"Time Late"; INDEX(IFNA(TEXT(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(Tardies!A2:A), 
 " (.*)")-VALUE("8:00"), "h:mm")))}
```

[image]